# Body background extends past the html div

Tags: html, css

I have an image slider I'm testing out to implement into my portfolio. I have the containing div (carousel) set to 100% width. However, I am still seeing about 200px of the body background color to the right of the div, which is also causing a horizontal scroll bar to appear. When I try to inspect the elements on the page I am seeing the html div as the width of the carousel but the background color set to body extends beyond that for some reason.

I've tried changing the positioning and margins but can't figure out what I've overlooked. Here is the css for the large elements and the page http://marjib.com/test/test1.html

Someone please help :)

---

```
body { 
margin:0 auto;
background-color: #333;
}

.carousel {
margin:0;
width:100%;
height:630px;
background-color:#EEE;
position:absolute;
}

.slides {
padding: 0px;
width: 850px;
height: 630px;
margin: 20px auto;
position:relative;

}

.slides * {
user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

.slides input { display: none; }

.slide-container { display: block; }

.slide {
top: 0;
opacity: 0;
width: 850px;
height: 556px;
display: block;
position: absolute;

transform: scale(0);

 transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
}

.slide img {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's `width:100%` on your `.nav-dots` remove that and it should be fine. It's taking the width of the document on load but then when you absolute position it a fixed amount from the left it's pushing it over the body width causing that extra spacing.

Comment: Only tested this out in the inspector window but seems to work. Thanks to both for the response. This was driving my nuts.

Answer (score 0):

Change your .nav-dots CSS

```
.nav-dots {
    display: block;
    height: 11px;
    left: 360px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 580px;
}
```